# What is the correct way to insert JavaScript in Twig templates

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, twig

I want to display the vote of films with drop down list which contains JavaScript, but I' don't know what is the correct way to use JavaScript in Twig templates. I've got `query.dropdown.js` and `modernizr.custom.63321.js` in `...\PYSBundle\Resources\public\js`. In `base.html.twig` I've got:

```
        (...)
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( function() 
            {
                $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In `frontend.html.twig`which extends of `base.html.twig` I've got:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@PYSBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.dropdown.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {% javascripts '@PYSBundle/Resources/public/js/modernizr.custom.63321.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

At finally in `votaciones.html.twig` which extends of fronted.html.twig` I've got:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
    <option value="-1" selected>Select a vote -</option>
    <option value="1" class="one">1</option>
    <option value="2" class="two">2</option>
    <option value="3" class="three">3</option>
    <option value="4" class="four">4</option>
    <option value="5" class="five">5</option>
    <option value="6" class="six">6</option>
    <option value="7" class="seven">7</option>
    <option value="8" class="eight">8</option>
    <option value="9" class="nine">9</option>
    <option value="10" class="ten">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the way I do this thing

First, define the libraries you use all the time in this application and put them in `app/Resources/public/js/` folder

<kbd>**app/Resources/public/js/**</kbd>

- jquery.min.js
- jquery.dropdown.js
- modernizr.js

Then, create an `assetic.asset` to fetch them easily

<kbd>**config.yml**</kbd>

```
assetic:
    assets:
        libraries:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery.dropdown.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/modernizr.js'
```

Then, create a single js file which will hold your javascript bundle logic

<kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/public/js/frontbundle.js**</kbd>

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {

// Define the routes to deffer execution of javascript
// "all" matches all the pages
// "bodyId" defines the ID of the body
var Routes = {
    'all': [ 'hello' ],
    'bodyId': [ 'foo' ]
}

var Mods = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log('Hello world');
    },

    foo: function() {
        console.log('Foobar');
    }
}

function frontbundle() {
    this.bodyId = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].getAttribute('id');
}

frontbundle.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.run('all');
        this.run(this.bodyId);
    },
    run: function(id) {
        var route = Routes[id];

        if (undefined === route) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {
            Mods[route[i]]();
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var app = new frontbundle;
    app.init();
})

})(window, document, jQuery)
```

The way I did to deffer execution of javascript needs to set an `id` to the `<body>` of each page.

Then, just import all of them in your base template

<kbd>**@Bundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig**</kbd>

```
{% javascripts
    '@libraries'
    '@Bundle/Resources/public/js/frontbundle.js'
    filter='yui_js'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: The single JS file you say, it's my `jquery.dropdown.js`. Basing on that, I followed your instructions but I still does not work

Comment: I've solved by putting these lines:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function(){
        $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown();
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you require assets by: composer require symfony/asset

This is if you are using symfony of course.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/functions.js') }}"></script>
```